# Вызов пока еще необъявленной функции в Nim

Tags: nim

Компилятор ругается на вызов Bar из Foo т.к. он еще не объявлен, не подскажите как все таки реализовать это или что то похожее?

```
proc Foo(args: type) = 
  ...
  Bar(args)

proc Bar(args: type) = 
  ...
  Foo(args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось предельно просто, нужно было лишь перечитать туториал (https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html). В общем код должен выглядеть как то так:

```
proc Bar(args: type) 

proc Foo(args: type) =
  ...
  Bar(args)

proc Bar(args: type) =
  ...
  Foo(args)
```